# Turnkey Net-SNMP

Tags: linux, net-snmp

Trying "apt-get install net-snmp" command to use SNMP commands. but the server says "Unable to locate package net-snmp"

This is where I'm told I require Net-SNMP; http://php.net/manual/en/snmp.requirements.php

but it looks like net-snmp isn't available from the repositories of this installation

This is for a Turnkey Linux web server.

Please help?

Comment: Which SNMP command do you need? As a command line programs or from a language such as PHP?

Answer (score 1):

I reckon you want to install the `php5-snmp` package.

FWIW, TurnKey Linux is based on Debian. TurnKey v14.x = Debian Jessie.

FYI I discovered that by doing a [package search](https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages) (scroll about halfway down to "Search package directories") for "php snmp" in "oldstable" (i.e. Jessie). If you'd done a search from the commandline, you probably would have found something similar. E.g.

```
apt-cache search snmp php
```

Like most other commandline tools, you can also leverage grep if you get too many results.